# Storing username in nginx logs

Tags: nginx, logging, django

Is there a way in which user-name or user-id can be stored in nginx logs. I tried inserting $remote_user in the log_format directive but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.  However, since you aren't using HTTP basic auth, you will need your application to tell Nginx what the current username is.  Add a response header along the lines of:

```
X-Username: nishant
```

Then in your `log_format` directive, use the variable `$sent_http_x_username`.  This behavior is documented here:  http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#.24sent_http_HEADER

I also recommend removing this extra header from the response before sending it to the client.  You can do this with the [NginxHttpHeadersMoreModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpHeadersMoreModule).

```
more_clear_headers 'X-Username';
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how to add a response header?

Comment: @nishant That depends entirely on your code.  You will have to write something or modify what you have to output the username in the response header.

Comment: The web application is based on django.

Comment: @nishant I haven't written anything with Django so I can't give you specific advice, but it looks like it supports middleware.  I would write a middleware module that takes care of adding the extra header.